# Finding intersection of arrays not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have a two dimensional array with an arbitrary number of elements in each dimension, so it's an [m][n] array, but the second dimension length (`n`) is variable.

Each element in the second dimension contains a number and there will only be one number that exists in all of the dimensions.

So, for example, the array might be:

```
[
    [
        126, 
        131, 
        138, 
        139, 
        140, 
        143
    ],
    [
        126,
        201
    ]
]
```

Keep in mind that `m` can be > 2.

Here's my code:

```
var theArray = [
  [126, 131, 138, 139, 140, 143],
  [126, 201]
];

for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) // loop through each array of numbers
{
    $.each(theArray[i], function(index, value) // loop through all of the numbers in this array
    {
        var nextArray = (i+1<theArray.length?theArray[i+1]:theArray[0]);
        if($.inArray(value, nextArray) == -1) // if this number is not in the next array
        {
            console.log("removing index: " + index + ", value: " + value);
            theArray[i].splice(index, 1); // remove the number from the array
        }
    });
}
console.log(theArray);
```

The output is this:

```
removing index: 1, value: 131
removing index: 2, value: 139
removing index: 3, value: 143
removing index: 4, value: undefined
removing index: 5, value: undefined
removing index: 1, value: 201

Array
    [
        [
            126, 
            138, 
            140, 
        ],
        [
            126
        ]
    ]
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hDL8K/

As you can see, it *almost* works, but it fails to remove two of the values.

I think this might have something to do with the `index` in the `foreach` loop increasing with each loop and the array size decreasing because elements are being removed, but I'm not sure.

Why is this not working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Modifying the array you're iterating through often doesn't work, because when you splice an element out of it, all the indexes for the remaining elements move down.

Comment: Hi Nate, I added a solution that does not modify original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Functional version with jQuery`](http://jsfiddle.net/yNcEz/)

```
var theArrays = [[126, 131, 138, 139, 140,143],[126, 201]],result = theArrays[0];

$.each(theArrays, function(index, currentArray) {
    result = $.grep(result, function(currentElement) {
        return currentArray.indexOf(currentElement) !== -1;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Simple JavaScript version:

```
var theArrays = [[126, 131, 138, 139, 140,143],[126, 201]],result = theArrays[0];

for (var i = 1; i < theArrays.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j += 1) {
        if (theArrays[i].indexOf(result[j]) === -1) {
            result.splice(j, 1);
            j -= 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ 126 ]
```

If the arrays are too big, then its better to convert them to Objects and then find the intersection. Because item lookup in Objects will be much faster for larger arrays.

```
var theObjects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < theArrays.length; i += 1) {
    var tempObject = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < theArrays[i].length; j += 1) {
        tempObject[theArrays[i][j]] = true;
    }
    theObjects.push(tempObject);
}

var intersection = theObjects[0], result = [];
for (var i = 1; i < theArrays.length; i += 1) {
    for (var key in intersection) {
        if (theObjects[i].hasOwnProperty(key) === false) {
            delete intersection[key];
        }
    }
}

for (var key in intersection) {
    result.push(parseInt(key));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really slick! I noticed, however, that the code modifies the original array (`theArrays`). Is there any way around that?

Comment: @Nate Does your environment has ES5 implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, so I guess not :-)

Comment: @Nate Where are you intended to use this code? Latest browsers/node.js?

Comment: The only library I'm using is jQuery and I'm trying to make my website as cross-browser & version friendly as possible. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I found that I can create a copy of the array by using `.slice(0)` and then work off of that, which leaves the original array unmodified! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nate You are welcome :) I am trying something else, if it works, I ll update my answer.

Comment: @Nate Please check the jQuery version now

Comment: Just checked out the jQuery version. That's fantastic, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I expect your problem stems from the fact that your array lengths are being modified as you remove items from the array. Rather than manipulating the array directly, you could have a function construct a new array with your result. I find in general this approach can help reduce bugs in code. From your existing code it could be something like this:

```
function intersect(theArray){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++){
        var row = [];
        $.each(theArray[i], function(index, value){
            var nextArray = (i+1 < theArray.length
                             ?theArray[i+1]:theArray[0]);
            if($.inArray(value, nextArray) != -1) {
                row.push(theArray[i][index]);    
            }
        });
        result.push(row);        
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/grundez/CMg7N/1/). Though that does produce a multidimensional array containing intersections - you may just want the first element of it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly where the problem in your solution is, but..
Here you have a solution

```
var theArray = [
  [126, 131, 138, 139, 140, 143],
  [126, 201]
];

//Finds intersection of 2 arrays, returns new array
function intersect_safe(a, b){
  var ai=0, bi=0;
  var result = [];    
  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else{ /* they're equal */     
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }
  return result;
}

for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++){ // loop through each array of numbers    
    var nextIndex = (i+1) % theArray.length;
    theArray[i] = intersect_safe(theArray[i], theArray[nextIndex]);
}
console.log(theArray);
```

**EDIT**: If you want to find the intersection *without* modifing the original array, just change the last lines of code by:

```
var intersection = theArray[0] || [];
for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++){ 
    intersection = intersect_safe(intersection, theArray[i]);
}
console.log(intersection);
```

**Output:** `[126]`

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 1):

I updated your method a little bit:

```
for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) // loop through each array of numbers
{
    $.each(theArray[i], function(index, value) // loop through all of the numbers in this array
    {
        var nextArray = theArray[i + 1];

        if(nextArray !== undefined && $.inArray(value, nextArray) == 0) 
        {
           console.log("removing index: " + index + ", value: " + value);
           theArray[i].splice(index, 1); // remove the number from the array
        }

    });
}
```

Try it now: http://jsfiddle.net/SabdielRivera/hDL8K/2/